# predict if news article belong to specific category or not?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, nlp, svm, text-classification

I am still new to machine learning. I am trying to build an ML model to predict if an article belongs to a category or not.

for example, I have three categories : [war, politics, and crime].

I choose a category I want to check if the news article belongs to it or no
and the model predicts if the article belongs to this category [yes/no]

i think about two approaches :

1. make three binary classifiers, a classifier for each category,
   predict [yes belong/no(not belong)]
2. one classifier that predicts the category of the article.

my questions:

1. which approach is better for me ? (the one which gives the highest accuracy ?)
2. how does the dataset of approach 1 look? maybe a file that includes two columns [article content, category] and category values be [1,0] (1 means yes belongs to this category)
3. if I use approach two, How to handle the case That article does not belong to any of my categories. (should I check probabilities and set a threshold)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.